# Should vendor perfixes in css be used for both property name and value or only value?

Tags: html, css, npm, webkit, vendor-prefix

I had scaffolded my project with webapp generator. The project uses sass. When the sass is compiled to css it automatically vender perfixes. I suppose this is being acheived by auto-perfixer. It converts the following code:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
        transition: transform .6s ease-in-out, opacity .6s ease-in-out;       
        backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

into the following

```
 .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out, opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out, opacity .6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
            backface-visibility: visible;
  }
```

I am curious about this lne:

```
transition: transform .6s ease-in-out, opacity .6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
```

It contains both `transform` and `webkit-transform` but doesn't use vender perfix for property name `tansition`. My question is if a certain browser needs `webkit` perfix for `value` then it must need that perfix for property name too, then why does `autoperfixer` not use vender perfix for property name?

Comment: The answer is, it depends on the property and the vendor.

Comment: @MrLister Could you explain for only transition property?

Comment: Well, your assumption that "if a certain browser needs webkit perfix for value then it must need that perfix for property name too" is not correct. For instance, MDN says for [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility) that Chrome needed the prefix until v35, but for [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#Browser_compatibility), the prefix was needed until v25. So in other words, between Chrome 26 and Chrome 35 you needed to write `transition: webkit-transform...`